# Symfony : EventSubscriber. trigger a 404 page when a route require user must be authenticated (depending of the .env var)

Tags: symfony, symfony4

In my project, I create some controllers and some routes.

I added to some controller and some specific route this condition "`@IsGranted("IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY")`" like this :

[image]

Depending of the env variable, I want to disable routes who need to be authentificated (disable = redirect automatically to a 404 page). My question :

From a EventSubscriber, how can I check if the current route need an anthentificated user ?

Comment: Please, do not add code as images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`kernel.exception` event](https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/error_pages.html#use-kernel-exception-event) to get notified of a 403 / Forbidden exception that Symfony will automatically throw in this situation.
In the event handler you can override the response and replace it with a `RedirectResponse`:

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\ExceptionEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;

class ControllerListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            KernelEvents::EXCEPTION => 'onException',
        ];
    }

    public function onException(ExceptionEvent $event)
    {
        // implement custom logic and set your response, eg.:
        // $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse(...))
    }
}
```

Another way is to override the [`framework.error_controller` configuration](https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/error_pages.html#overriding-the-default-errorcontroller) and implementing a custom controller. Within the configured controller action you can the also return a `RedirectResponse`.

```yaml
# config/packages/framework.yaml
framework:
    error_controller: App\Controller\ErrorController::show
```